# Radio turns off once key is turned on

Tags: audio

I'm installing a new radio in a 84 F250 and I'm running into some issues. For some reason I have power when the key is off, but once I turn it on I lose power. What could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you've got the two power sources switched backwards. There are two sources going to two different leads on your stereo. One of them is going to be to provide power to your head unit so you retain settings while the car is off. The while the other one will be for when the car is on and is the main source. When you turn the ignition from off to Accessory, the power switches. One goes on and the other goes off. I'm going to bet you don't have both power sources hooked up, and then you have the power source going to the wrong lead on head unit.

Comment: I have the accessory and power wires hooked up to the power wire coming off the radio. It is the only way to turn it on. is that bad?

Comment: @Haveaniceday - I don't know that it's "bad", but it wouldn't be right. Even with an older truck like yours, it should still have two separate power leads for it.

Comment: It does, but using them separate doesn't seem to want to work.

Comment: I lied. I had power and accessory from the radio hooked up to power from the truck. And I tried it again and now nothing works :P

Comment: Which is what I was suggesting in the first place. Glad you got it figured out.